# Как подружить Swing и синхронизированные потоки

Tags: java, swing, многопоточность

Пишу плеер, и возникла заминка в следующем: есть главный поток из Swing, и есть параллельные ему потоки, которые должны запускаться последовательно друг за другом. Как подружить эти потоки, но так, чтобы и параллельные потоки запускались друг за другом и графический интерфейс не "замерзал" при работе этих потоков?

`tagTopTracks` хранит коллекцию треков для воспроизведения, требуется проиграть весь этот плейлист последовательно.

`AppGUI` (сокращенно) - Swing-интерфейс

```
public class AppGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private TopTracks tagTopTracks;
private int trackNumber;
private Track track;

PlayerClass player = new PlayerClass();
private void playButtonMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    while (trackNumber < tagTopTracks.getTopTracks().size()) {
        getTrackFromTopTracks(trackNumber);
        player.stop();
        player.play(track.getTrackURL());
        trackNumber++;
    }
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new AppGUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

}

Класс, который заведует плеером:

```
public class PlayerClass {

private static URL url;
private static InputStream is;
private static BufferedInputStream bis;

public Player player;

public void stop() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.close();
    }
}

public void play(String fileURL) {
    try {

        url = new URL(fileURL);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        is = connection.getInputStream();
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        player = new Player(bis);

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

    } catch (IOException ex) {

    } catch (JavaLayerException ex) {

    }

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                player.play();
            } catch (JavaLayerException ex) {

            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

И здесь возникают проблемы с последовательным воспроизведением треков из плейлиста: новый трек начинает играть, не дожидаясь окончания предыдущего, накладываясь на него, потом третий, четвертый и так далее.
Если же сделать метод `run()` синхронизированным, то треки, как и требуется, играют один за одним, но тогда "замерзает" GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно пересмотреть архитектуру вашего плеера. Вместо того, чтобы в цикле запускать потоки с воспроизведением, попробуйте заставлять поток воспроизведения песни автоматически запускать следующую по окончанию воспроизведения. Для того, чтобы поток знал, какую песню запускать следующей, нужно либо при создании потока-песни передавать ссылку на следующую (негибко, не позволяет динамически менять плейлист), либо хранить плейлист в каком-нибудь месте, где к нему будут иметь доступ потоки, воспроизводящие песни (читайте про паттерн "[Синглтон](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))"). Более гибкий вариант - по окончанию воспроизведения трек генерирует событие, которое ожидает какой-нибудь менеджер воспроизведения (читайте про паттерн "[Наблюдатель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))"), который, в свою очередь, по этому событию запускает воспроизведение следующего трека.

Comment: Отлично, решил проблему передачей в PlayerClass ссылки на плейлист. А с помощью паттерна "наблюдатель" передаю информацию о текущих событиях в GUI (информацию о треках, сервисные сообщения)

Answer (score 0):

Не вдаваясь в суть задачи... Можно использовать `Executor`, полученный следующим образом: `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`

Comment: Опишите подробнее, как можно это использовать для решения поставленной задачи, этим вы улучшите свой ответ.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал ознакомится с этими статьями. Там очень подробно все описано. [Теория и практика Java: Пулы потоков и очередь действий](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp0730/), [Обзор java.util.concurrent.*](http://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/157273/), [Многопоточность в Java: ExecutorService](http://habrahabr.ru/post/116363/). Ну, и, конечно [официальная документация](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Comment: @ Timofey Bondarev,  пример, если требуется назначить выполнение кода с промежутком 1 секунда между выполнениями:
`ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() { ... }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Answer (score 0):

Запускай проигрывание музыки в другом потоке, используя [Swing Worker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html)

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Я уже думал об этом, но получилось пойти другим путем - передаю классу PlayerClass не отдельный трек, а ссылку на плейлист, а дальше класс сам планирует следующий трек взаимодействуя напрямую со списком треков

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение проблемы. Изменил код класса PlayerClass. Теперь метод play() принимает на вход плейлист и вызывает метод playTrack() для проигрывания отдельного трека. По окончании проигрывания playTrack() снова вызывает play(). Такая себе рекурсия.

```
public void play(List<Track> playlist) {
    stop();
    currentTrack = playlist.get(new Random().nextInt(playlist.size()));
    currentTrack.setTrackURL(currentTrack.toString());
    stringTrackURL = currentTrack.getTrackURL();
    playTrack(stringTrackURL);
}

private void playTrack(final String trackURL) {
    if (trackURL != null) {
        try {
            url = new URL(trackURL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            is = connection.getInputStream();
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        } catch (MalformedURLException | ConnectException ex) {
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }

    audioThread = new Thread("audioThread") {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                isPlaying = true;
                if (trackURL != null) {
                    for (PlayListener listener : LISTENERS) {
                        listener.PlayerStarts();
                    }
                    player = new Player(bis);
                    player.play();
                }
            } catch (JavaLayerException ex) {
                // skip track if JavaLayerException
            }
            if (isPlaying) {
                play(CURRENT_PLAYLIST);
            }
        }
    };
    audioThread.start();
    isPlaying = false;
}
```